# How to get background type of Emacs? e.g. 'light or 'dark

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to get background type of Emacs? e.g. `'light` or `'dark`

You can define a face like this:

```
(defface moedict-type
  '((((class color) (background light))
     (:foreground "#ffffd7" :background "#525252"))
    (((class color) (background dark))
     (:foreground "#525252" :background "#c1c1c1")))
  "Face for type. ex: [動]、[名]")
```

And Emacs will select correct font face automatically by current background type.
But I want to know how it do. (It is better if there is an build-in function in Emacs)

By the way, I try to seek in source code and found a function (frame-background-color), but its output is string like "#ffffff".

Comment: You can use `set-background-color` to set the desired color of current frame. Do `C-h f set-background-color`. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, I exactly want to get current background color type...

Comment: Check the variable `frame-background-mode`, it seems to be what you want

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: Please put your comment in an answer, which can be accepted or voted up (or down).

Comment: @Drew You are right, I should posted the above as an answer (which the community could have voted on), got a bit carried away, sorry! Will be careful next time.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: Consider adding info about `frame-background-mode` to your answer.

Comment: @Drew, Thanks for the suggestion, actually I later realized that `frame-background-mode` was probably not what kuanyui was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the function `frame-parameter` to get the attributes of a frame. For your particular case you can do

```
(frame-parameter nil 'background-mode)
```

To get background-mode of the current frame. The first parameter is the frame for which you want to the get specified parameter, if nil the currently selected frame is used. You can do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`frame-parameter`<kbd>RET</kbd>